# Using mysql GROUP_CONCAT and WHERE

Tags: mysql, group-concat

I have the following tables in my DB

**EVENT**

```
ID, TITLE, ...
```

**VOTES**

```
ID, TYPE, ID_EVENT
```

**COMMENTS**

```
ID, COMMENT, ID_EVENT
```

**DATES**

```
ID, DATE, ID_EVENT
```

One EVENT has many actions, has many comments and **has many dates**.

I'm using following query to retrieve info from EVENTS table, and for each event retrieve the number of votes, the number of comments and each one of the dates. For events with one of their date = tomorrow (2015-04-03)

```
        SELECT  events.id,
                events.title,
                GROUP_CONCAT(dates.date) AS dates, 
                COUNT(distinct votes.id) AS votes,
                COUNT(distinct comments.id) AS comments
        FROM events 
        LEFT JOIN dates on dates.post_id = events.id
        LEFT JOIN votes on votes.post_id = events.id AND votes.type = 1
        LEFT JOIN comments on comments.votes_id = votes.id
        WHERE dates.date = CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY
        GROUP BY events.id
```

Result looks like this

```
id    title    dates                            votes  comment
33    Event33  2015-04-03,2015-04-03,2015-04-03 4      0
39    Event39  2015-04-03                       9      1
```

Why the dates column repeats the same date (tomorrow)??? The dates of Event33 should be 2015-04-01, 2015-04-02, 2015-04-03.

What is wrong?

Comment: You probably want to `GROUP BY events.id` and use `distinct` inside the `GROUP_CONCAT()`, as you did with `COUNT()`

Comment: sorry ypercube, the group by was a writing mistake. i edit it. The query works fine without WHERE clause for listing all events. But don´t works when i add where clause to filter by date

Answer (score 0):

You want the events that have **one** of their dates tomorrow. Your query does that but it also cuts off all other dates.

You need an extra join or an `EXISTS` subquery.

You also need a `DISTINCT` on the `GROUP_CONCAT()`, the same way you used it at the `COUNT()` aggregate:

```
SELECT  events.id,
        events.title,
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT dates.date) AS dates, 
        COUNT(DISTINCT votes.id) AS votes,
        COUNT(DISTINCT comments.id) AS comments
FROM events 
  LEFT JOIN dates ON dates.post_id = events.id
  LEFT JOIN votes ON votes.post_id = events.id AND votes.type = 1
  LEFT JOIN comments ON comments.votes_id = votes.id
WHERE EXISTS
      ( SELECT 1
        FROM dates AS dd
        WHERE dd.date = CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY
          AND dd.post_id = events.id
      )
GROUP BY events.id ;
```

Another way would be using inline subqueries. No need for `GROUP BY` or `DISTINCT` in this. A minor disadvantage in your case, is that the join to `comments` is through `votes`, so one subquery has an extra join:

```
SELECT  e.id,
        e.title,
        ( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(d.date)
          FROM dates AS d
          WHERE d.post_id = e.id
        ) AS dates, 
        ( SELECT COUNT(v.id)
          FROM votes AS v
          WHERE v.post_id = e.id AND v.type = 1
        ) AS votes,
        ( SELECT COUNT(c.id)
          FROM comments AS c 
            JOIN votes AS v ON c.votes_id = v.id  
          WHERE v.post_id = e.id AND v.type = 1
        ) AS comments
FROM events AS e 
WHERE EXISTS
      ( SELECT 1
        FROM dates AS dd
        WHERE dd.date = CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY
          AND dd.post_id = events.id
      ) ;
```